# Apply a function on part of a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I defined a function:

```
my_func <- function(vector1) 
{ // do something 
vector2 //vector 2 has the same length with vector1 
}
```

Now, I have a dataframe:

```
id1 id2 value
1 1 0.6
1 1 0.7
1 1 0.2
1 2 0.4
1 2 0.8
```

I want to create a new column `value2` in the dataframe, by apply the function `my_func` in each part of dataframe's value, with same `id1` and same `id2`. It means, I want to call

`my_func(dataframe[dataframe$id1 == i & dataframe$id2 == j,]$value)`

with all possible `i` and `j`.
and assign these new values to corresponding rows in new column `value2`.

**Update:**

The output should looks like:

```
id1 id2 value value2
1 1 0.6 3
1 1 0.7 4
1 1 0.2 9
1 2 0.4 2
1 2 0.5 3
1 2 0.8 4
1 3 0.3 2
...
```

when the [3, 4, 9] is the result of `my_func` on the [0.6, 0.7, 0.2], and [2,3,4] is the result of `my_func` on [0.4, 0.5, 0.8] ...

Comment: Please show your expected output and what is `my_func`?

Comment: ``my_func`` is just a function to calculate in a vector and returns a vector, e.g, ``my_func` takes a list of 10 numbers and produce other 10 numbers.

Comment: Based on the input data, what is the expected output?

Comment: @akrun I added the expected output, thanks

Comment: It is not clear how you got `3 4 9`

Comment: Hi @akrun, `` 3 4 9`` comes from function ``my_func``, basically if I put the input of ``my_func`` as ``0.6 0.7 0.2``, it will return ``3 4 9``

Comment: You should have told that you are grouping by 'id1' and 'id2'.  In that case `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(id1, id2) %>% mutate(value2= my_func(value))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it similar to this:

```
my_func <- function(vector1) 100+vector1
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'id1 id2 value value2
1 1 0.6 3
1 1 0.7 4
1 1 0.2 9
1 2 0.4 2
1 2 0.5 3
1 2 0.8 4
1 3 0.3 2')
d$v3 <- ave(d$value, d$id1, d$id2, FUN=my_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using 'id1' and 'id2' as grouping variables, we can use either `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id1, id2) %>%
    mutate(value2= my_func(value))
```

---

or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, value2:= my_func(value),  by = .(id1, id2)]
```